# Draw roadmap for a vehicle positioning

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

We have a vehicle tracker service which basically returns the vehicle position (latitude and langitude) at every minute. I need to draw the vehicle position on the road map as soon as service retuns it. I'm exploring the bing-map features but not able to find out any solution yet.

Just to clear the requirements, I know the feature where we can design the map with single latitude/langitude point. But with realtime, my requirement is to show multiple positions of the vehicle on the map. Can you please help me on this ASAP.

Thanks & Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

In order to create static imagery based on Bing Maps, you can use the dedicated Imagery service in REST or SOAP:

- For SOAP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981090.aspx
- For REST: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

You should be able to generate map in road style for the several location of your vehicle.